# Can I change my appearance?

Tags: mass-effect-3

In my rush to get started playing on Tuesday, I hastily accepted the appearance of my imported Shepard.  After playing for a while now, I've grown to hate the way he looks.  Is there any way, in game or out,  for me to alter Shepard's appearance without having to start over?  Answers involving third party, unsupported editors are fine with me, as long as it includes some sort of proof that it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You unfortunately can't change your appearance mid-game [(not without a belt-sander....)](http://www.dorkly.com/comic/32951/how-to-change-your-appearance-in-mass-effect-3), though you CAN change your imported character's appearance **when you import your character**. This can only be done at the start of the game.

There are some unoffical projects that are trying/planned to edit ME3 save files like [this one](http://code.google.com/p/me2-sge/) but **as of yet you can not edit Mass Effect 3 save data**. Give it some time and this may change however, the game hasn't even been out a week and the save data is very complex.

Answer (score 5):

You can get the Mass Effect 3 save editor [here](http://svn.gib.me/builds/masseffect3/).

[image]

Start a new game to customize a face, then play until you are able to save.
Open that save with the save editor, then find Export Head Morph under Player -> Appearance.
Open your current playthrough in the save editor and import the face.

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to change your look once you step in game. All decisions made during character creation are permanent.

There was an unofficial save editor for Mass Effect 2 that allowed you to change your face, so if you wait a while (or search hard enough) you should be able to find something similar.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! I'd upvote you, but I don't yet have 15 rep. Sorry. Well, it seems I may have to just make a new character, because that nose is REALLY bothering me.

Answer (score 0):

In lexi's lab on the tempest you can change your appearance and your twins.