# Can I change my character's face?

Tags: mass-effect-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I change my appearance?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/54354/can-i-change-my-appearance)

You see, I played Mass Effect 1 and 2 on consoles, not PC. So I cannot import my character from those games. I quickly threw together a character in ME3 because I assumed I could edit it later. The only decisions I bothered to focus on were the where are you from and are you a war hero, ruthless, or something else I forgot. My character has the ugliest hairstyle, and he has a nose that would be big on an elephant. I've also been comparing his nose to other characters in the game, and it looks broken too! Or bent, whichever.

So, plain and simple, how the heck do I fix my face? I know the ladies are just being nice to me because I saved their asses on more than one occasion, but I know deep down they can't stand to look at me. I'm about 10 hours in, and I don't really want to go back and redo everything just to make Shep. sexified.

Thanks, guys!